# Copying file itself to another directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to copy(clone) the file itself to c:\Temp\ directory. However, I 'm getting "directory is not declared" error when building my file in Vb.net.

```
    Sub main()

    Dim FileToCopy As String
    Dim NewCopy As String

    FileToCopy = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    NewCopy = "C:\Temp\microsoft.exe"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then

    System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)

    End If


End Sub
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: Do you have using statements on top of the file for System.IO?  If not you need `System.IO.Directory` instead of `Directory`

Comment: The issue here is that you're calling `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, which gives you... a directory. Calling `File.Exists`, and furthermore `File.Copy` expects a full file path including the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FileToCopy = Application.ExecutablePath

Good luck making that worm :3